# Script para enviar cadenas masivas a mis contactos en Facebook

Tags: web, script, facebook

Soy prácticamente nulo en programación web usando JavaScript o Python o cualquier otro lenguaje relacionado en ese ambiente.
Quiero poder ejecutar un script que reconociendo que mi sesión de Facebook está abierta envíe un texto predeterminado a todos los contactos que tenga agregados en Facebok.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato pues es muy amplia u basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esto, te recomiendo que uses **Python** con la librería **[selenium.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)** Esto es porque con selenium tienes muchas posibilidades para interactuar con los elementos de las webs **(clase, id, nombre)**

Por ejemplo, puedes crear un Bot para Iniciar Sesión en **FaceBook**
 simplemente enviando teclas a los elementos de las webs como los **`<input>`** o los **`<textarea>`** (los campos de usuario y contraseña).

Y luego, ir hasta llegar al campo de enviar texto a un contacto.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero por favor tratemos de no responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues terminan cerradas, al no sujetarse al formato del sitio